# IMagicExtension :Unable to read image from the filehandle

Tags: php, imagick

I have installed

- PHP  5.5.15
- Apache 2.4.10
- ImageMagick-6.7.7-5-Q16-windows-dll
- php_imagick-3.2.0RC1-5.5-ts-vc11-x86

Imagick extension has installed correctly. but when i run the following code

```
$handle = fopen($url,"rb");
```

$img = new Imagick();
   $img->readImageFile($handle);

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Unable to read image from the filehandle'

Thanks in advance

Comment: check whether you are able to read file, might be permission issue. try $handle = fopen($url,"rb") or die('could not read file');

Comment: Reading files from a URL is just not good. Use a library that is designed to do that properly (e.g. Curl) to download the file, and then open it in Imagick as just a normal file.